# Difference between $P(Y \ge y)$ and $P(Y > y)$.

Tags: probability-theory

In the book "[Probability: Theory and Examples](http://www.ime.usp.br/~manuelg/arquivos/Probability%3a%20Theory%20and%20Examples%20-%20Durrett.pdf)", there is this theorem:

> Lemma 2.2.8 If $Y \ge 0$ and $p > 0$ then $\mathbb E(Y^p) = \int_0^\infty py^{p-1} P (Y > y) \,  \mathrm dy$.

The proof is by using Fubini's Theorem as follows

\begin{align*}
\int_0^\infty py^{p-1} \mathbb P (Y > y)  \mathrm dy
& = \int_0^\infty \int_\Omega py^{p-1} 1_{(Y > y)} \, \mathrm dP \, \mathrm dy \\
& = \int_\Omega \int_0^\infty py^{p-1} 1_{(Y > y)} \, \mathrm dy \, \mathrm dP \\
& = \int_\Omega \int_0^Y py^{p-1} \mathrm dy \mathrm dP  \\
& = \int_\Omega Y^p \mathrm dP = \mathbb E Y^p \\
\end{align*}

For me it seems totally fine to replace $Y > y$ with $Y \ge y$ in this proof, but the conclusion would be $\mathbb E(Y^p) = \int_0^\infty py^{p-1} P (Y \ge y) \,  \mathrm dy$. So if $Y$ can only take nonnegative integer values, we have $\mathbb E Y = \sum_{y \ge 0} P(Y \ge y)$, which is wrong.

So why we can not replace $Y > y$ with $Y \ge y$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lemma 2.2.8 is equally valid when one replaces $P[Y\gt y]$ in the integral by $P[Y\geqslant y]$ because $P[Y\gt y]=P[Y\geqslant y]$, for almost every $y$ **with respect to the Lebesgue measure**, since the set of values of $y$ such that $P[Y\gt y]\ne P[Y\geqslant y]$ is at most countable.

This holds for **every** nonnegative random variable $Y$, either continuous or discrete or neither continuous nor discrete.

Comment: The assertion involving $\sum\limits_{y\geqslant0}P[Y\geqslant y]$ in your post makes no sense (and is nowhere in the book).

Comment: So actually we can replace $>$ with $\ge$ in the proof? I'm confused because latter in the book, exercise 2.2.7, a generalized version of Lemma 2.2.8 is given, with $>$ replaced by $\ge$, that's why I'm considering whether there are difference between the two.

Comment: Both statements are valid--this might explain why the book uses both.

Comment: As for the sum, I was thinking if $>$ and $\ge$ versions of Lemma 2.2.8 is equivalent. Then we should have $\mathbb E(Y) = \int_0^\infty P (Y \ge y) \,  \mathrm dy = \sum_{y \ge 0} P(Y \ge y)$, for $Y$ takes only integer values which seems to be wrong.

Comment: If $Y$ is almost surely a nonnegative integer, then $[Y\geqslant y]=[Y\geqslant n]$ for every $n-1\lt y\leqslant n$ and every integer $n\geqslant1$ hence $\int_0^\infty P[Y\geqslant y]\mathrm dy=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty P[Y\geqslant n]$, as was to be expected.

Comment: Thanks! Somehow I believed the sum should starts from $0$ without much thinking.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong with: $\mathbb E Y = \sum_{y \ge 0} P(Y \ge y)$ as long as $Y$ takes non-negative integer values. See the Wikipedia section on [Discrete distribution taking only non-negative integer values](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Discrete_distribution_taking_only_non-negative_integer_values).

Comment: As you pointed out in the link, the sum should start from $y \ge 1$, not $y \ge 0$.

Answer (score 1):

As observed by $\textbf{Did}$, the lemma is equally valid when $P(Y > y)$ is replaced by $P(Y \ge y)$, since $P(Y > y)=P(Y \ge y)$ almost everywhere; this applies to *every* non-negative random variable $Y$.

In general, however, $P(Y \ge y)$ and $P(Y > y)$ are equivalent if and only if $P(Y = y)=0$, which is always true for continuous random variables, since a single point leaves the integral unaffected. For discrete random variables, this is not the case, since a point does affect the sum.

Finally, I am not sure where your formula for the expectation of a non-negative discrete random variable $Y$ comes from; as you noticed, it is easy to [derive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Discrete_distribution_taking_only_non-negative_integer_values) that

$$\operatorname{E}[Y] = \sum\limits_{y=1}^\infty P(Y \ge y).$$

Comment: But the integral $\int_0^\infty py^{p-1} 1_{(Y > y)} \, \mathrm dy$ should not change if we replace $>$ with $\ge$, right? This is an integral with respect to Lebesgue measure, which shouldn't change when omitting a single point.

Comment: @ablmf Yes, I have completely revised the answer.